# Android activity flow best practices

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

I am wondering what is the best way to design the flow of my app in Android. There would be 5 main sections, so I was thinking in using 5 Tabs for this purpose. Inside every "section"/tab should be also some kind of navigation, so the user would navigate to new Activities, and here is were it comes a little bit tricky because I am not sure what would be the expected behaviour for the back button.

Applications such as Instagram have a similar structure and then when a user hits back he gets to the last Activity he was in, no matter if that is in a different Tab.

Comment: You can achieve this using TabGroupActivity.

Comment: Yep, technically is possible, the problem is how you would move between tabs when hitting back...

Comment: TabGroupActivity is deprecated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use Tab and Fragments. Its really nice to implements fragments if you want to navigate inside a Tab. You can see the doc for [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) here. Here is the nice tutorial on Tab[ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/index.html).

And for back button you can use some flag for it. Update with the change and choose what to show to user when flag changes.

For start you can see this example on stackoverflow.[Implementing action bar tabs with fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974120/implementing-action-bar-tabs-with-fragments).

Comment: Thank you, I think the combination of ActionBar + Fragments is the way to go in Android in equivalency to iOS TabBar + Navigation inside every tab.

Comment: Yes that is the way to go in android. ;-) Feeling happy that it helped you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

After reading your application concept I have suggest to use ***Fragments***.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

> A **Fragment** represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

So you can use this and after that extends your Activity with ***FragmentActivity*** in which you can call your five *tabs*.

And it is easy to call new fragment or navigate to other screen using Fragment. You have to just keep in mind that you have maintain the ***backstack*** of every Fragment.